# Use controller on fortnite when window is not focused

Tags: controllers, windows-10, fortnite-battle-royale

I have the problem that I have to share my pc with my sister. We usually manage to use it at the same time when one of us is playing a game using a controller and the other one is doing something different in another window. I would love to play fortnite in this setup, but unfortunately, the controller input isn't accepted when fortnite is not focused. Some games like GTA V have an option to enable this, for fortnite I only found the option to enable music when the window is not focused, but not to enable controller input.

Is there something I can do to get fortnite working for me? E.g. a command line parameter or something?

Thanks very much for your help!

Edit: It's not a duplicate of [Playing a steam game with a controller while using other applications (Multi-Monitor)](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/158598/playing-a-steam-game-with-a-controller-while-using-other-applications-multi-mon) , because there is no solution in the other question that is applicable to this one and it is specific for fortnite, so maybe finding a solution is more realistic than finding a general solutions for all games. It could be some kind of hidden start parameter etc.